# Android: How to cross-fade two midi tracks?

Tags: android, midi, cross-fade

Is it possible to cross-fade playback between two midi tracks with Android? The `MediaPlayer` API seems to support only one track at a time.

Comment: I'll take a closer look at the [`JetPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/jetplayer.html) - possibly capable of that (?)

Answer (score 0):

Try the answer provided here: [Audio Crossfading in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661596/audio-crossfading-in-android)

Basically you probably need to mix the two tracks (and adjust the volume of one audio source) yourself and pass the resulting audio data to a [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html)

Comment: Comments on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20115908/1725096) questions state that `AudioTrack` does not support the midi format ..

Comment: Yeah you are probably right, but without Android native crossfade support, I don't think you can achieve it with MIDI formatted data.